# What design approach to use when a variable is used both for Adding In-Memory and For DbInsertion?

Tags: c#, timer

I have a collection as SocketData which is getting filled continuously from a connected socket. As of now we were adding data the moment we receive data on the socket. But as our application grows the frequency is getting increased.

This is leading to performance issues and with the current approach it may open multiple connections to database.
We want to re-design our approach (below code is the prototype).
Collection variable lstSocketData is getting filled continuously.
We will wait for say 5 mins till that all data will be in-memory collection of 
lstSocketData.
After configurable time we will raise an event to Insert data in Database.
How should I handle FailOver, and how should I remove Succesfull Added enteries from the collection. We do not want to loose any of the data.

If I use same variable for live Add and AddToDatabase then it is possible to loose data. 
Should I take a copy of current collection using                               `var addInDbCollection = DeepCopy(lstSocketData)` and send that collection for Insertion. If Insertion fails then Add the collection in Failover mechanism.

Please suggest some approach/design.

```
public class ActivePassive
{
    private static Timer timer = new Timer();
    private static Timer timerDbInsertion  = new Timer();

    private static ICollection<SocketData> lstSocketData = new Collection<SocketData>();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();

        timerDbInsertion.Interval = 5000;
        timerDbInsertion.Elapsed += timerDbInsertion_Elapsed;
        timerDbInsertion.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void timerDbInsertion_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //// Make a call to add in Database
        //// connector.AddInDatabase(lstSocketData);

        //// After successfull completion of Insertion clear the SocketData collection.
        //// In Case of Failover then take the SocketData collection and insert in some flat file.

        try
        {
            //// Add In database.

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //// Failover(lstSocketData);
            throw ex;
        }

    }


    static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //// taken timer elapsed event to fill data. In real app it is coming from MSMQ/TCP socket.
        lstSocketData.Add(new SocketData() { Id = new Random().Next(), Date = DateTime.Now });
    }
}

public class SocketData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You may benifit from using of [ConcurrentBag<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx) collection that allows thread-safe way of working with collection items.

Comment: Or possibly the Queue<T> class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx. You would need to add you own synchronization if accessing from different threads.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to save the data as it arrives in a file on the local file system and upon reaching particular file size start a procedure for flushing it to the DB. To make sure no data is lost due to OS crash or power outage, make sure you call `FileStream.Flush` appropriately.

Another approach is to directly employ a local database for saving raw data as it arrives and replicate to the main DB as needed. It doesn't need to be SQL server DB - OleDb will be fine for a temp DB. As I can remember it's free and already deployed on almost any Windows machine, although SQL Server Express is free too and is more than enough for the purpose...

However, since you don't want to loose any data it isn't wise to rely just on in-memory storage until the time for flushing come.

Comment: yeah I agree I should not be depending on In-Memory collection. I would prefer to use SqlLite or Compact Framework (.sdf) for the local storage purpose.